# Converting an excel file string to imaginary excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am reading an excel file as a text, and I am posting this string to server. However, I couldn't convert this string to a proper data structure to use it as an input for apache poi functions without creating a temp file in the file system. What I want to do is this;

Excel String -> An Excel File Object (imaginary) -> Reading data from this imaginary file

I don't want to create a temp file every time someone tries to upload an excel file.

I tried something like this;

```
InputStream stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(OntologyContentTxt.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
    HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream);

    HSSFSheet sheet=wb.getSheetAt(0);
    HSSFRow row;
    HSSFCell cell;

    Iterator rows = sheet.rowIterator();

    while (rows.hasNext())
    {
        row=(HSSFRow) rows.next();
        Iterator cells = row.cellIterator();

        while (cells.hasNext())
        {
            cell=(HSSFCell) cells.next();

            if (cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue()+" ");
            }
            else if(cell.getCellType() == HSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC)
            {
                System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue()+" ");
            }

        }
        System.out.println();
    }}
```

But it gives me this error.

> org.apache.poi.poifs.filesystem.NotOLE2FileException: Invalid header signature; read 0xE011BDBFEFBDBFEF, expected 0xE11AB1A1E011CFD0 - Your file appears not to be a valid OLE2 document

How can I make this kind of convert?

Thanks.

Comment: What line does this occur, on the instantiation, the cast, what?

Comment: HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(stream); this line does.

Comment: An Excel file can never be stored in a string. It is either a binary file (`*.xls`) or a ZIP file containing XML and binary files (`*.xlsx`). Both cannot be transported in a text string.